# Recording Line Numbers of Executed Paths

Tags: google-chrome-extension

For Google Chrome Extension, is it possible to record the sequence of line numbers (with file names) (with the existing variables values in case of JavaScript) that are executed during the execution of HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: Depends. Is it your own code?

Comment: Not really, I am referring to general Website. But is being my code important? @Xan

Comment: Well, you can add the ability to your own code.. Tracing someone else's code without modifying it is another topic.

Comment: @Xan tracing other's code is what I am looking for. Google chrome extension is a mean that I am hopeful supporting that. Other means are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible but *exceedingly* difficult.

One can, in principle, implement it using [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger), which gives the same access to the page as DevTools.

However, that API basically consists of sending almost-raw [Remote Debugging protocol commands](http://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-1/), and there aren't many samples to go on with. [Debugger domain](http://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-1/Debugger/) seems relevant.

So, it's possible but it's a lot of work, and additionally it's going to slow execution to a crawl.

---

As such, this is not a good problem to solve with extensions. It's better served by modification of Chromium code and maybe existing debugging capabilities of it. Basically, to efficiently output this information you need to get down to browser internals.